# minChars in autocomplete() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am doing demo for autocomplete using jquery plugin.
I have to set the minimum character length to 3. 
I have changed minChars : 3 in its default options values.

```
$.Autocompleter.defaults = {
    inputClass: "ac_input",
    resultsClass: "ac_results",
    loadingClass: "ac_loading",
    minChars: 3,
    delay: 400,
    matchCase: false,
    matchSubset: true,
    matchContains: false,
    cacheLength: 10,
    max: 100,
```

Also I tried it by changing adding the minChar parameter on autocomplete() call like:

```
   $("#inputSchool").autocomplete(data, "option", "minChars", 3);
   and also like :
   $("#inputSchool").autocomplete(data, "{minChar : 3}");
```

But yet is is not working. Please tell me the solution.

And How to Edit the format of autocomplete list?
i.e. I have to add multiple values html like :

```
<ul>
   <li>value1, value2 
       <br /> 
       value3
   </li>
</ul>
```

Please Help me?

Comment: Which auto complete plugin are you using?

Comment: Which version of autocomplete are you using? I recommend you use the latest that is part of jqueryui - http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ Then the setting you will need to set is minLength

Comment: What does "not working" mean in this case? What actually happens?

Comment: I am using  "http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete".
When I set the minChars property of "options" to 3, the autocomplete list will not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Are you searching something like :

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ minLength: 3 }); // Not minChars
//or
$("#inputSchool").autocomplete("option", "minLength", 3);
```

Comment: yes.. Actually I tried that. But not working..
I am using  "http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete".
When I set the minChars property of "options" to 3, the autocomplete list will not appear.

Comment: I believe he was pointing out using "minLength" instead of "minChars".

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
   $("#inputSchool").autocomplete(data, {minChars : 3});
```

Comment: mhm may its no longer working with the latest version of jquery. you may try http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/